Join two objects and merge vertices darker shading
I joined two objects in Blender and merged the vertices. I wonder why the head is shaded a little bit darker. I made the whole object smooth shaded afterwards. The normals seem to be okay too:



hello could you please share your file?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i-dZD6SBsTPTDVNdJU6MCTjdxeGd9iSP?usp=sharing here you go

The head and body use different colors on the Materials > Viewport Display > Color panel (below the normal Materials section). Go into Edit mode and in Face Select mode, compare the Viewport color on a body and head Face! For that matter, the head uses Head_SG as its material and the body uses Default so the rendered colours will be different too.

Your Viewport Shading is set to Material instead of Object:

So you'll see the color set for this object in the Material panel under Viewport Display:


Thank you very much. :)
